# is onCreate() called in an Activity that implements Runnable?

Tags: java, android

I am calling a runnable Activity with the code

```
Mover simulationRuntime = new Mover();
```

The `onCreate()` does not run what gives?

Answer (score 0):

That's the wrong way to start an activy. You should use the `startActivity` method Google provides for you

Answer (score 0):

`onCreate` is only called by the framework, when the framework instantiates the activity. To start another activity from your code create an `Intent` and then use `startActivity`.

When you create a `Mover` object like in your code example just the constructor will run.

Comment: So using this  Intent intent = new Intent(this, Mover.class);
                startActivity(intent);
how do I pass the bundle to the surfaceview?

Comment: You can add extras to the intent (see `Intent.putExtra` in the documentation)